# Chest workouts without pull-ups or bench-presses

Tags: exercise, chest

What chest exercises are available for people who don't have access to a pull-up bar or a bench/barbell? Are there any specific exercises that stand out as extremely good?

Comment: Dips and pushups. How about fly exercises with (improvised) dumbbells?

Comment: yeah do you have dumbbells ?

Comment: @Greg Yes, I have several dumbbells ranging 8 - 50 lbs.

Comment: @TheChaz Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Pull-ups are a chest exercise? I assume you mean either pull-up bar dips or muscle-ups ON a pull-up bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By request...

I would recommend

- dips (which can be done with various arrangements of common household furniture, or on a counter-top)
- pushups, of which there are MANY kinds/varieties/ranges of motion
- fly exercises with your (improvised) dumbbells.

Answer (score 2):

Wide Push-Ups; one of the best compound exercises available yet will isolate the width of the chest more so than a Close Push-Up. Combine both [Wide/Close](http://www.livestrong.com/article/321226-wide-push-ups-vs-close-push-ups/) to target the majority of your chest.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this : http://scoobysworkshop.com/chest-exercises/#pushups

There is plenty of good chest exercise in their, only requirement is dumbell ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what others have suggested. In addition, [Pullovers](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/DBPullover.html) are a great exercise for both the chest and back, done with dumbbells or a barbell. I regularly incorporate them into my chest training. There are several variations - flat bench/decline bench, and bent or straight arm.

Dumbbbell or Kettlebell  [Floor Presses](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/dumbbell-floor-press) are an oft-forgotten cousin of the much more popular bench press, and as the name suggests do not require a bench.

You could try flyes one-armed to test your stabilizing muscles and independently work both sides, personally I have found one-armed flyes to be very beneficial.